# C++11 Start new thread from class constructor and error

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, c++11

I saw on stackoverflow a few idea to start thread from class.

My func - this func have to be run

```
//header.h
private:
void updateTime();
//cpp
void class::updateTime(){
    while (true){
        Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

From my class constructor ( this is QT class constructor )

I try with that:

```
std::thread t1{&class::updateTime,this};
```

Or in lambda style

```
std::thread t1{ [this] { updateTime(); }  };
```

But i still got a error

[image: http://i.imgur.com/DnOvEDp.jpg]

I thought that methods should work ;0 Debugger return this:
[image]

Comment: Make sure you join the thread before its destructor is called (or detach it, but meh).

Comment: What is `void class::updateTime()`? It is totally nonsense.

Comment: But where i have to detach it, if i want to this thread work all the time? In destructor ? But then how to init thread after init a var i.e (in (.h) `private: std::thread t1;` and in constructor how to pass function to this thread? )

Comment: @Thomas You should describe what it is that you're trying to do. And please post code that compiles instead of made up stuff. As Nawaz says, your current example is nonsense. If the destructor for a thread object that is `joinable` executes, then `std::terminate` will be called. To prevent this you need to either `join` or `detach` the thread. When, where, how you do this depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Okey, in my program (with QT libs) i have got qdatetimeedit - which keeps my time. My new thread have to control this time (thats why while(true) and Sleep 1s ). I know about QTimer but i want to use threads from c++ libs, it would be better than QTimer. So my thread must start with program and shutdown with program. (So this thread must work ALL the time witch program is running)

Comment: @ThomasBanderas, You use a constructor initializer list to initialize data members. Or you can use a non-static data member initializer since this is C++11. Just think more than twice before detaching a thread.

Answer (score 2):

From the description in the comments, it sounds like you want your class to be somewhat like this:

```
struct foo
{
    void updateTimer()
    {
        while(running_) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
            std::cout << "Hello" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    std::atomic_bool running_{true};
    std::thread t_{&foo::updateTimer, this};
    ~foo()
    {
        running_ = false;
        t_.join();
        std::cout << "Thread stopped\n";
    }
};
```

The above class launches a thread upon construction, which prints `Hello` once every second until it is signaled to stop. This signaling is done by `~foo()`, and this is necessary because without it, the [destructor for `t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/~thread) would execute while it is `joinable`. This would result in `std::terminate` being called. It is necessary that an `std::thread` that is joinable be either `join`ed, or `detach`ed, to prevent this from happening.

Here's [an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3d189c0615f3f49a) of the above class being used.